# HTTPS SOAP request outputs junk characters in response headers

Tags: ruby, ssl, soap, https, jruby

To make SOAP HTTPS call I write this method in jRuby.

```
def run host, port, path, soap_request_file,password,protocol = "HTTP"


    soapMsg = ""
    request = ""

    soap_request_file = Expertus::TestDataFile::get_file_relative_to_script(soap_request_file)
    
    soapMsg = IO.read(soap_request_file)

    request = "POST #{path} #{protocol}/1.1\r\n"
    request = request + "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n"
    request = request + "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n"
    request = request + "Content-Type: application/soap+xml\r\n" if soapMsg.downcase.include?("soap-envelope")
    request = request + "Content-Length: #{soapMsg.length}\r\n"
    
    request = request + "Authorization: Basic #{password}\r\n"
    request = request + "\r\n"
    request = request + soapMsg
    request = request + "\r\n"
    
    log.debug("Trying to connect to SOAP service on #{host}:#{port}")
    # Sending request
    socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)
    log.debug("Sending request to SOAP service")
    log.debug("#{request}")
    socket.send(request, 0)
    
    # Reading response
    log.debug("Reading SOAP service response")
    response = socket.read
    headers,body = response.split("\r\n\r\n", 2)
    log.debug("Received SOAP service response headers #{headers}")
    log.debug("Received SOAP service response body #{body}")
    log.debug("Closing SOAP service connection")
    socket.close
    log.debug("Connection with SOAP service closed")
    
    return headers,body    
  end
```

When I make HTTP call, I get correct response back : Received SOAP service response headers HTTP/1.1 200 OK

but when I make HTTPS call, I get "Received SOAP service response headers §♥♥ ☻☻P".

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I wonder why you build the request by yourself and do not use a SOAP client gem like [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon)?

Comment: Yes, I should have. I was using jruby 1.7.3 and build this to make a WS calls and there are lot of tests written around this. We recently upgraded to jruby 9 and started supporting HTTPS in our software. Any idea why would I get these junk characters for HTTPS specifically ?

Comment: You should really not try to re implement HTTP yourself. Use the relevant library in your language, or even the SOAP relevant one. But at least do not do HTTP by hand. You are also obviously not doing HTTPS but mere HTTP otherwise a simple `TCPSocket` wouldn't be enough. You can not just do TCPSocket on port 443 and expect that to work, HTTPS needs more code.